# ssh throws bad host name and no output

Tags: ssh

I have script that goes in each server and gets output.

```
 EXCECUTE_CMD="$(find /tmp/customize -name 'customize.*.log' -mtime -1 -type f -print | wc -l)"

  for server in $SERVERS
  do
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $server $EXCECUTE_CMD
  echo "$server $EXCECUTE_CMD" > $text.txt
  done 

  echo "file fullpath"; ls -ltra $text.txt
}
```

right now i can not get ouput and i get error as bad host name: server1,server2. I need to get and add all the output's in each server and print in a file as total count.

Comment: `EXECUTE_CMD` should be a plain string not a command substitution at this point. drop the `$(` at the bginning and `)` at the end, while keeping the `"`s. QAlso, this can only works when all your servers are assigned to a variable called `SERVERS` in a space delimited form. If `SERVERS` is a file you need the contents of it. Such as `SERVERS=$(cat SERVERS)`

Comment: right now i do in the script is      if [environment 1];then servers="\server 1= 123\server 2= 456\"
if [environment 2];then servers="\server 1= 789\server 2= 1011\"

Comment: you can not do that. The variable SERVERS should be equal to just the server names not `\server1=this_server\server2=that_server`. It should be like `SERVERS="server1 server2 server3"` just the list of servers. That is why it says it can not find the server.

Comment: Hello MelBurslan your solution has fixed my problem now it goes to each server and gets the data i need through ssh but their is one problem left that the output i get is not printed in to a file, if i try to print it it doen't add all the outputs from each server i get as total .....any solution for that please.

Comment: I have modified your code to make it work and posted it below. If you are going to do shell programming in the future, can I suggest that you get [THIS BOOK](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596526788.do) and use it as reference. I have noticed a lot of conceptual mistakes in your code. I think you are confusing shell programming with some other scripting or programming language as far as the syntax rules go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EXCECUTE_CMD="$(find /tmp/customize -name 'customize.*.log' -mtime -1 -type f -print | wc -l)"

for server in ${SERVERS}
do
  count=$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${server} ${EXCECUTE_CMD})
  echo "${server} ${count}" >> text.txt
done 

echo "file fullpath" ${PWD}/text.txt
```

Comment: Your solution prints the output in a file but doesn't totals the output MelBurslan. expected output: total is 6    actual output : server1 3  server2 3

Comment: add this line to the bottom of the script: `printf "the toal file count is: ";awk '{sum+=$2} END {print sum}' text.txt` for the sum